# FTP upload to any upload center and get download link by python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

this is my code , i want to upload a file via ftp to nitroflare or uploadgig or any uploadcenter and after finishing upload file get the download link from upload center site

```
import ftplib
filename = 'photo_2019-02-17_22-49-08.jpg'

session = ftplib.FTP('ftp33.nitroflare.com','Username','password')
file = open('photo_2019-02-17_22-49-08.jpg','rb')                
session.storbinary('STOR photo_2019-02-17_22-49-08', file)    
file.close()                                   
session.quit()
```

Comment: How does this code not do what you expected of it?

Comment: @Reedinationer actually it works right and uploading file is OK but i want to know how can i get the download link of that file uploaded by this code , i have no idea about this mission